# Not working "Manually running a workflow." in github action

Tags: github-actions

I have created below workflow expecting github to ask the manual input and then run the rest of steps. However I don't see any button `run workflow` [such-as-this](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-07-06-github-actions-manual-triggers-with-workflow_dispatch/). The workflow shows "null" value in the "print steps" of my workflow.(see attached the screenprint)

Does anyone knows what is wrong and why it's not prompting me any inputs?

```
name: Input Workflow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      myInput:
        description: 'User Input:'
        required: true
        default: "Hello World"
  push:
    branches:
      - feature/*



jobs:
  run-python-test:
    runs-on:  ubuntu-latest
    steps:

      - name: Execute Test Script
        run: |
          echo "Store: ${{ github.event.inputs.myInput }}"
          # INPUT_STORE=${{ github.event.inputs.myInput }} python3 input.py
```

[image: outcome-workflow]

Comment: This is fixed by adding the workflow in default branch. `https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow#running-a-workflow-on-github`

Answer (score 0):

[`inputs`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#providing-inputs) is a property of [`workflow_dispatch`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch) event but not [`push`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#push) event:

```yaml
name: Input Workflow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      myInput:
        description: 'User Input:'
        required: true
        default: "Hello World"
  push:
    branches:
      - feature/*
```

Comment: thanks and you are right, I have modified my questions because it still doesn't prompt me any inputs. @tmt

Comment: I think i fixed it....as per document `https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow#running-a-workflow-on-github` the workflow_dispatch should be in default branch first.

Answer (score 0):

The issue of not showing up any input parameters in GitHub action is due to fact that the `workflow_dispatch` is not present in default branch. [definition](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow#running-a-workflow-on-github)